# Grab current session's cookie with cURL

Tags: bash, curl, cookies

I'm working on a script that send a POST request to an URL, actually I'm sending the cookies manually in the header.. but how to take it from the current browser session?

I used tcpdump and grep but it's really the wrong choice :,D 
Some suggestions?

I wont take them from a file but from the browser session and without enter in the cookie path of the browser

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Curl can handle that for you; there is an option to store the cookies in a cookiejar and use those in subsequent requests.

Here is an example from the main curl site, which uses cookies from a file cookies.txt to set some and at the same time stores new cookies in newcookies.txt.

http://curl.haxx.se/docs/httpscripting.html#Cookie_Basics

```
curl --cookie cookies.txt --cookie-jar newcookies.txt  http://www.example.com
```

When going through a login process, for example, one would reuse the cookies from cookie jar.

Comment: It would be useful to provide an example showing what you mean here, in case the link changes in future.

Comment: Ok but this is the same to take from an input... I want to take the cookies from the browser session without go inside the cookie path

Comment: So you were talking about your *browser session* all the time?

Comment: Yes, i was sure i wrote it.. Sorry

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked that: just export the cookies and use them with curl:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/161778/how-do-i-use-wget-curl-to-download-from-a-site-i-am-logged-into

Answer (score 0):

I had found a link now broken with an example from snipplr.com. I'll post it here for future references (credits to the owner):

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

if (isset($_COOKIE[session_name()])) {
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, session_name().'='.$_COOKIE[session_name()].'; path=/');
}

session_write_close();
$result = curl_exec($ch);

if (curl_errno($ch)) {
  echo 'curl error: '.curl_error($ch);   
}

curl_close($ch);
session_start();
```